# Rails routes with optional parameters priorities

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, rails-routing

I have an strange issue in my routes file.
This is the part that I need to understand
This routes doesn't work

```
  # V3
  # V3 - Home Page
  match '/:locale' => 'v3/home#index', :constraints => V3Constraint, :as => :home
  # V3 - Search
  match '(/:locale)/products/search' => 'v3/products#search', :constraints => V3Constraint
  # V3 - Categories index
  match '(/:locale)/categories/(:parent_category((/*path)/:category))/(:full)' => 'v3/products#index', :constraints => V3Constraint, :as => :category
  # V3 - Prduct Page
  match '/:locale/products/:product' => 'v3/products#show', :constraints => V3Constraint, :as => :product
  match '(/:locale)/search_amazon' => 'v3/products#search_amazon', :constraints => V3Constraint
  # EOF V3
```

But this work

```
#V3 - Search
  match '(/:locale)/products/search' => 'v3/products#search', :constraints => V3Constraint
  # V3 - Categories index
  match '(/:locale)/categories/(:parent_category((/*path)/:category))/(:full)' => 'v3/products#index', :constraints => V3Constraint, :as => :category
  # V3 - Product Page
  match '/:locale/products/:product' => 'v3/products#show', :constraints => V3Constraint, :as => :product
  match '(/:locale)/search_amazon' => 'v3/products#search_amazon', :constraints => V3Constraint
  # V3 - Home Page
  match '/:locale' => 'v3/home#index', :constraints => V3Constraint, :as => :home
```

If I made the Home Page route have less priority than the others it works, but if it was on the top like the other
this route:
     match '(/:locale)/search_amazon' => 'v3/products#search_amazon', :constraints => V3Constraint
will be leading to the home page.

Can any please explain why this is has to happen ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a route like this `<yourdomain>/search_amazon` will match the first one of these two routes

```
match '(/:locale)/search_amazon' => 'v3/products#search_amazon', :constraints => V3Constraint
```

In this case, it will match because `locale` is optional here.

```
match '/:locale' => 'v3/home#index', :constraints => V3Constraint, :as => :home
```

While here it will match making `search_amazon` as the value for `locale`.